# Elasticsearch default analyzer not analyzing

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to define a default analyzer for when I index types like so:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/index" -d '{
"index" : { 
    "analysis" : { 
        "filter": {
            "english_stop": {
              "type":       "stop",
              "stopwords":  "_english_"
            },  
            "english_stemmer": {
              "type":       "stemmer",
              "language":   "english" 
            },  
            "english_possessive_stemmer": {
              "type":       "stemmer",
              "language":   "possessive_english" 
            }   
        },  
        "analyzer" : { 
            "default" : { 
                "tokenizer" : "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "standard",
                    "english_possessive_stemmer",
                    "lowercase",
                    "english_stop",
                    "english_stemmer"
                ]   
            }   
        }   
    }   
}   
}'
```

But when these types are searched, it seems like the documents are not analyzed because the values in fields are not lowercased, they are not stemmed, and stop words are not removed. Am I doing something wrong? I am trying to analyze documents without defining the document structure. This [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_controlling_analysis.html) led me to believe that setting the default analyzer index should analyze the documents I insert into `index/_type`.

**Updated:**

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:26319/index" -d '{
"settings" : { 
    "analysis" : { 
        "filter": {
            "english_stop": {
              "type":       "stop",
              "stopwords":  "_english_"
            },  
            "english_stemmer": {
              "type":       "stemmer",
              "language":   "english" 
            },  
            "english_possessive_stemmer": {
              "type":       "stemmer",
              "language":   "possessive_english" 
            }   
        },  
        "analyzer" : { 
            "default" : { 
                "tokenizer" : "standard",
                "filter": [
                    "standard",
                    "english_possessive_stemmer",
                    "lowercase",
                    "english_stop",
                    "english_stemmer"
                ]   
            }   
        }   
    }   
}   
}'
```

Here is the search I am running:

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/index/_type/_search?q=penn+state+jersey&pretty"
```

Here is the mapping:

```
{
  "index" : {
    "mappings" : {
  "_type" : {
    "properties" : {
      "description" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "keyphrases_general" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "keyphrases_specific" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "unique_id" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "vendor" : {
        "type" : "string"
      }
    }
  }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example of a document:

```
{
  "_index" : "index",
  "_type" : "_type",
  "_id" : "518875234",
  "_score" : 1.1152786,
  "_source" : {
    "keyphrases_specific" : "Office Merchandise Tailgating Outdoor Clothing Man Cave",
    "name" : "Penn State Nittany Lions Classic Football Keychain - Licensed NCAA Gift - Penn State Nittany Lions Merchandise",
    "description" : "Check out this Penn State Nittany Lions Classic Football Keychain - Licensed NCAA Gift - Penn State Nittany Lions Merchandise. This product is perfect for a Penn State Nittany Lions fan. Show off your pride and add a great piece to your man cave! Made By Gamewear",
    "keyphrases_general" : "Sports Bedding Drinkware Licensed Dï¿½cor Accessories Gift",
    "vendor" : null,
    "unique_id" : null
  }
}
```

It's also strange because `penn state jersey` and `penn state jerseys` return different search results, even though I would think they should return the same since jerseys should not be plural anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a small typo: `index` should be `settings` at the first level of your JSON

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/index" -d '{
"settings" : {              <--- change this
    "analysis" : { 
        "filter": {
```

Make sure to delete your index first and try again, that will work.

Comment: Wow! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks! I've changed it to settings, but when I search the results the analyzer still doesn't seem to be applied to the search fields. Will the default analyzer be used for all types of fields?

Comment: Actually, I may be wrong. I thought that the the analyzed text would be stored in the field, but it looks as though it may be stored elsewhere, so maybe it is working. I guess I'm just not sure how to tell.

Comment: Can you show the search you're running? And also your mapping?